# Load data from MySQL TO Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Hi I am Using the following scirp file in lostash 2.X version I have over 186000 records in MySQL database table,but while running this .conf file only one document is loading in elastic search index.

```
input {
        jdbc {
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost/elasticsearch"
            jdbc_user => "root"
            jdbc_password => "empower"
            #jdbc_validate_connection => true
            jdbc_driver_library => "/home/wtc082/Documents/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            statement => "SELECT * FROM index_part_content_local;"
            #schedule => "* * * * *"
            #codec => "json"
        }
    }

output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "mysqltest"
        document_type => "mysqltest_type"
        document_id => "%{id}"
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
}
```

When i use this query only one document is index

```
GET mysqltest/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}




{
  "took": 14,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "mysqltest",
        "_type": "mysqltest_type",
        "_id": "%{id}",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "partnum": "",
          "property1": "",
          "property2": "",
          "color": "",
          "size": "",
          "dim": "",
          "thumburl": "",
          "catid": "6575",
          "subcatid": "3813",
          "termid": "31999",
          "longdesc": "<ul><li>Equipment and Parts<li>GC32-XD Parts<li>D/V Lock Plate Screw</ul>",
          "hier1desc": "Heavy Duty Tools / Equipment",
          "hier2desc": "Other Heavy Duty Equipment",
          "hier3desc": "Hose Crimping Equipment & Accessories",
          "aaiabrandid": "BBSC",
          "aaiabrandname": "Gates",
          "brandimageurl": "es-logo-sm.jpg",
          "linecode": "GAT",
          "descrp": "D/V Lock Plate Screw",
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2016-12-20T09:16:40.075Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full document/result you're getting?

Comment: I have updated the Document  ,Thanks for your help in advance Val,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as you can see the ID of your document is the verbatim value `"%{id}"`, which means that apparently you don't have any `id` column in your database and all records from your database are indexed under the same document id, hence why you only see one document.

In your `elasticsearch` output, you need to make sure to use a field that is the primary key of your table

```
    document_id => "%{PRIMARY_KEY}"
```

Fix that and that will work.

Comment: OMG...!!!!!  you are god of ES Val , thanks for helping .....I wish when ever I post any question ,u s'be the one who will answer it ,eveytime.                      Became a huge fan of yours........